# How could simple SVGs take more bytes than PNGs?

Tags: svg

We have icons created in Adobe Illustrator that need to be sent over a network connection and rendered at 72x72px, and we have control on both ends over how they're rendered. We need a small file size. They're fairly simple icons, but in SVG form, they're anywhere from 32KB to 6KB, and when I render them as 72x72px PNGs, they end up being smaller, around 3KB!

How could this be possible? I thought SVGs were supposed to be much smaller since they're just vector representations. Is there some optimization I can do to make the SVGs smaller?

**Edit:** Here's an example. This is a Wikimedia SVG, not one of our icons, since I can't post our actual icons online. But it's similar to some of the icons we have and has the same problem:

PNG version, 2KB:

[image: Clock_02-30.svg rendered to 72x72 PNG]

[SVG version](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Clock_02-30.svg)
is 30KB. Comes out to 5KB zipped.

Comment: There is a ton of unnecessary metadata in the SVG files that AI exports. Open it up with a text-editor and you'll see that on the top(usually). You might also have a lot of unnecessary points in your lines which could be approximated with a single bezier curve - See this: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Quibik/Cleaning_up_SVG_files_manually#Adobe_Illustrator

Comment: Do you zip them before transferring them? If you want us to make any useful comments you'll need to provide at least one SVG icon in the question.

Comment: The zipped SVGs are considerably smaller than non-zipped SVGs but still larger than PNGs. I'm going to find an example to post...

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Thanks. I tried removing the metadata, but they're still too large. I'm going to try what that Wikimedia page suggests.

Comment: Hi, if you open your SVG with a text editor, you'll see that each dot for example needs a rough 400 bytes to bee encoded, whereas in your png, each dot is 4 pixels, which would need at worst (without any compression) 4 bytes (alpha, red, green, blue) *4 = 16 bytes.

Comment: What is to be understood, is that your SVG will be the same size (in terms of data), no matter at what zoom level you visualizes it,  whereas if you export as a bitmap, it's data size will depends on the resolution.

Comment: @mpiffault That's true, but the SVG isn't representing the entire image with individual dots in my case. There are a bunch of paths and such. It depends of course on how the image was created. Yes, it's scalable, but I'm always displaying it as 72x72px anyway.

Comment: The clock svg example contains quite a bit of crufty markup, a quick run through svgo makes it come out at ~2KB gzipped. Try https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ and see for yourself.

Comment: @ErikDahlström That's amazing. SVGO alone only results in about a 30% decrease in file size, but it somehow makes zip and gzip more effective because compressing the result makes it 1/4 or 1/5 the size. I'm going to use that then. I'll accept that as an answer if you want to post it.

Comment: You cannot generalize and think it is always smaller. It makes no sense. It all depends on the SVG and resulting image (and its resolution). Take a simple case of a gradient page that 8.5in x 11in in size @ 300dpi. That can be < 1kb in SVG and 50kb+ in PNG, 50 times larger.

Comment: @KevinBrown Yes, I'm only concerned about flat icons like the example, which we're using. I was surprised that a simple clock could be bigger as an SVG than as a 72x72 PNG. Actually, that optimization tool makes every flat icon I try smaller than the PNG form or about the same.

Comment: You said you used AI, but the sample file was clearly created with Inkscape.  By default Inkscape includes a lot of metadata. You can avoid this by selecting "Optimized SVG" when saving from Inkscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that SVGs can be small, here is a handcrafted version of your file that is only 922 bytes uncompressed.  It could be made smaller :)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500">
  <g transform="translate(250,250)">
    <g id="q">
      <g id="h">
        <rect x="198" y="-5" width="44" height="10"/>
        <circle cx="220" cy="0" r="5" transform="rotate(6)"/>
        <circle cx="220" cy="0" r="5" transform="rotate(12)"/>
        <circle cx="220" cy="0" r="5" transform="rotate(18)"/>
        <circle cx="220" cy="0" r="5" transform="rotate(24)"/>
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#h" transform="rotate(30)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#h" transform="rotate(60)"/>
    </g>
    <use xlink:href="#q" transform="rotate(90)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#q" transform="rotate(180)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#q" transform="rotate(270)"/>
    <circle r="22"/>
    <rect y="-5" width="150" height="14" transform="rotate(-15)"/>
    <rect x="-4" width="8" height="220"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```